# Can a vector space be reconstructed from its norm?

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $(V,+,\cdot,\|.\|)$ be a normed vector space. Can we reconstruct addition $+$ of vectors and scalar multiplication $\cdot$ if we are given only the underlying set $V$ and the norm $\|\cdot\|\colon V\to\Bbb R$?

Clearly, we can find $0\in V$ as it is the only element of norm $0$, and we know $1\cdot v=v$ and $0\cdot v=0$. And we have the topology. But is that enough to reconstruct the missing operations?

Comment: How do you know the topology? A norm induces a topology by defining a metric $d(x,y) = \lVert x - y \rVert$. But if you've forgotten the vector space structure, then you don't know how to subtract.

Comment: As a start on scalar multiplication, my intuition says that $2v$ is the element of largest norm in the $1$-ball around $v$. But I'm not even sure that's valid in your average function space.

Comment: @EthanDlugie. So let's say that one has a metric space. Two questions arise: 1) How can we see if the metric space is given by a normed vector space? 2) And when it is, is the vector space unique?

Comment: My above comment was wrong. As @Julian Rosen's answer highlights, the "$1$-ball around $v$" is not available to us in this situation; we can only define balls around $0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. If this were true, it would mean that every norm-preserving self bijection of a normed vector space preserved addition and scalar multiplication. A counterexample is $V=\mathbb{R}$ with $\|\cdot\|$ given by the usual absolute value. Then the self bijection
$$
\varphi(x)=\begin{cases}x&:|x|\leq 1,\\
-x&:|x|>1\end{cases}
$$
preserves the norm, but not the vector space structure.

Comment: $d(1/2, 3/2) = 1, d(\varphi(1/2), \varphi(3/2)) = 2$, no?

Comment: Yes, $\varphi$ does not preserve distance. But it *does* preserve the norm, and that is all the question requires.

Comment: D'oh, you're right! It's very hard to have a norm in the picture and not use the associated metric.

Comment: As all spheres in $\Bbb R^n$, $n>1$ have continuum cardinality, it follows that knowing only the underlying set and the norm function, we cannot even guess $\dim V$; dimensions $0$ and $1$ can be inferred, of course, but all other finite dimensions are indistinguishable.